# Use Range on non adjacent Rows for graphs in subroutine

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to set up several graphs with different non-adjacent rows for a line diagram (xlLineMarkers), but i cannot figure out how to hand over the defined ranges from a different sub.

Code as follows:

```
Private Sub butChart2_Click()

    Dim wbkKPI As Workbook
    Set wbkKPI = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)     
   
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range

    Set rngA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test2").Range("A:A")
    Set rngB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test2").Range("D:D")
          
    Call CreateChart2(wbkKPI, rngA, rngB)

End sub
```

The chart creating Sub:

```
Sub CreateChart2(wbkKPI As Workbook, rngA As Range, rngB As Range)

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim objChart As Object

  Set rng = wbkKPI.Worksheets("Test2").Range(rngA,rngB)
  Set objChart = wbkKPI.Worksheets("Test2").Shapes.AddChart2(Height:=400, Width:=500)
  objChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
  objChart.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
  
End sUb
```

The resulting chart uses Columns A to D as source instead of just A and D.
Where am I going wrong?

Due to the fact that I need to create like 10 charts, I would like to set the ranges in an Array and loop through them when calling the Chart sub routine.

thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but you could change `Set wbkKPI = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name) ` to `Set wbkKPI = ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe someone can help me with the other issue